# What Linux application can read PDX files?

Tags: pdf, search, software-rec, adobe-acrobat

I use openSUSE LEAP 15.2 with a KDE desktop, and I want to download some collections of PDF files that include an index (IDX and PDX files) for each collection. I'd like to be able to search and view the index files, and view PDF files from the hit list. The Adobe PDF Reader is very old and doesn't handle the latest formats. What packages are available for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
cat
```

PDX files are text/xml.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDX_(IPC-257X)

or maybe `zcat` because many formats (docx, epub) are text in zip.

```
file $EG.pdx
```

would tell you

Comment: I believe that pdx is an overloaded file type and that the link is nor fr the pdx used by Adobe to index collections of PDF files.